# Jquery file won't assign random height and width to element

Tags: jquery

as the title says: this won't work. The script does move the articles which I want to move, it also animates it if I put the option to the selector, but it won't **randomize** the `height` and `width` of the elements. All elements get a random width of 127px and I can't understand that. The mentioned php file in which the script is fetched, is below:

Updated:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.freetile.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    for (i=0;i<40;i++) {
        var w = 128 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1,h = 128 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1;
    jQuery('article').width(w).height(h);
    }

        jQuery('#content').freetile();
         selector: 'article';
         animate: true;
         elementDelay: 10
        });
    </script>
```

Is there something wrong with this part? That would be odd, because I literally copied and pasted it from the github repository.

```
    for (i=0;i<40;i++) {
        var w = 128 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1,h = 128 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1;
    jQuery('article').width(w).height(h);
    }
```

Here is the link to the files: 
https://github.com/yconst/Freetile/blob/master/js/init.js

Thanks ComputerArts, I have accepted your answer :)

Comment: This isn't the same as what's in github, in github the line looks like `$('<div class="element" style="color:#fff;"></div>').width(w).height(h).appendTo('.first.test');` they are creating a new div with the class 'element' and a style and appending it with a random size to the element .first.test.  And next time the file in the repo would be helpful, https://github.com/yconst/Freetile/blob/master/js/init.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explain your code

```
for (i=0;i<40;i++) {
    var w = 64 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1,
    h = 48 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1;

    //this part here is where the error happens.
    //you're asking to set the width and height to every element <content> on each iteration.
    //so on the last iteration, all the elements have the same width/height
    jQuery('content').width(w).height(h).appendTo('article');
}
```

I believe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ypVbc/) is what you want.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    for (i=0;i<40;i++) {
        var w = 64 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1,
            h = 48 * (parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1;
        $('<div class="content" />').width(w).height(h).appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks like it's working in the fiddle. I will test it out tomorrow and give you feedback. Thank you for your answer and input!

Comment: I have updated the code, I hope someone can check it out (again).

Answer (score 1):

Randomize the width and height of which elements? Your problem probably is that you're not passing anything to `jQuery()`

```
// What are you trying to set the width/height of?
jQuery('').width(w).height(h)
```

Probably should be something like

```
jQuery('#content .selector-for-tiled-divs').width(w).height(h)...
```

Comment: Even if I pass for example "article", it won't work. I have tried that, but it keeps having those pixels on every element. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @1BJK903 Just saying "it doesn't work" is a sure way to get people to stop helping you. Post the HTML you're using. How on Earth did you ever expect your `jQuery('')` code to work? Why would you call `jQuery('article')` and then `append('article')`?

Comment: @1BJK903 Fix your question with the actual code you're using! Post the  HTML! Don't post it here

Comment: I will post the actual code tomorrow, because I can't get it now (it was at work). You'll hear soon of me... Thanks for your answers btw.